# Justify-content: space-between is not working as expected

Tags: html, css

Would appreciate some help on this. So, I wanted to re-align the first picture to look like the second picture. I was expecting the `space-between` to distribute the space evenly in between so I've been trying to use `justify-content: space-between` which unfortunately doesn't work. Any idea why?

[image: current code]

[image: expected result]

HTML

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
    <div class="circle active">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn" id="prev" disabled>Prev</button>
    <button class="btn" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `progress` div take extra place in it, if you remove it from `progress-container` it looks same as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flex div all item get same width, if you set empty div then it's also consider as a one item of that flex div that's why your "progress" class div also get same width there is no matter there is data or not in the div.

To make your desire design make "progress" class hidden.

```
.progress {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is another `div` before the `circle 1`. It should be removed:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="circle active">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button class="btn" id="prev" disabled>Prev</button>
      <button class="btn" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/usf9Lcdg/

Answer (score 0):

this happened because of the id="progress" DIV that takes a space in the row ...

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli&display=swap");

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <title>Progress Bar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="progress" id="progress"></div>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="circle active">1</div>
    <div class="circle">2</div>
    <div class="circle">3</div>
    <div class="circle">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn" id="prev" disabled>Prev</button>
    <button class="btn" id="next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```